# modify contents of a js file

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have a javascript array of Url's in content.js file.  I need to display the urls in seperate input boxes on a seperate page say display.php. Edit and delete buttons are given along with each input boxes. any change made by the user should be reflected in the content.js file.

I have shown all the url's in the input boxes. now an onclick event calls a function on button press.

My question is what will be the best way to update the array in content.js file(the file contains only one array).  I'm trying to use file handling but that will require the content.js to have a strict format always. Is there a better way to modify the contents of the  array or delete rows from array without file handling?

Comment: Where does the "update" of the arrays comes from?

Comment: The urls will be displayed in the text boxes. the user is allowed to change the urls. when he clicks edit the change should be reflected in the array in the content.js file

Comment: Ok, than you *must* send it to any kind of dynamic webserver, write it there into a file.

Answer (score 1):

In first step, you should read the contents of JS file and pass it to [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) function. It will give you PHP array. Use this array to display text boxes to user.

In second step, you should get the strings the user was submitted (e.g. from `$_POST`) and construct a PHP array from them. Then use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) to convert PHP array to JavaScript array represented in a string. Then you can write this string to JS file. So its content will be always valid.

Comment: populate strings in PHP array?? I'm given a javascript object array in content.js file. So I originally have a javascript array. how should I go about converting this to php. Riateche please help

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a server-side language like PHP. See [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php) on how to write files using PHP. I would convert the array into a string using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) and use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) to convert it back into an array after [reading it](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php).

If you're only saving these URLs for the user and nobody else (so only the person entering/editing the data needs to see it) then I recommend using [HTML5 localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)